# Using PostgreSQL with Flask but without SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, flask

Can someone please help me with an implementation of creating RESTful APIs with PostgreSQL and Flask without using SQLAlchemy.

Coming from a NodeJS & MongoDB background, I used models with the help of Mongoose to query and add data to the DB by simply importing the models anywhere and using them.

But I haven't found a way around that using Flask and PostgreSQL without bumping into SQLAlchemy.

I have a project structure like below:

```
- api/
---| models/ # will contain the models(tables declaration)
------| __init__.py
------| User.py
------| Projects.py
---| resources/ # contains the logic files
------| __init__.py
------| users.py
------| projects.py
---|db.py
---|server.py
```

In my `/db.py` file i have the following code

```
import psycopg2
from flask import g

def connect_db:
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname='RSG_SQL'
    )

    con.autocommit = True

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT version();")
    record = cur.fetchone()

    print(con.get_dsn_parameters(), "\n")
    print("connected to db - ", record, "\n")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print('error while connecting to PostgreSQL', error)

    finally:
        # close db connection
        if (con):
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            print('connection to db closed')

    return con

def close_db:
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

And in my `/server.py` file I have

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, current_app, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from db import connect_db

from resources.users import AllUsers, SingleUser

# connect to db
con = connect_db()
if 'db' not in g:
    g.db = con

# create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# use flask_restful resource routing
api = Api(app)

# setup the Api resource routing here
api.add_resource(AllUsers, '/users')
api.add_resource(SingleUser, '/users/<user_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # set application to debug mode
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True #TODO: remove this line before production

    app.run()
```

The goal is to accomplish this without using SQLalchemy and connecting to the database just once and not everytime a request is made, because creating the database connection is expensive and will slow down the response time.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at using [connection pools](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html). An example can be found [here](https://pynative.com/psycopg2-python-postgresql-connection-pooling/)

Comment: @That1Guy Checked out...but using it to create models isn't clicking

Comment: Please write answer if you found the solution. I am interested in it.